# My rat is not shown moving when I run both classes

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, maze

I have a Maze class and a Rat class. They both communicate using a 9 character string protocol using sockets, and the rat tells the Maze how it wants to move. The Maze moves it. In order to show that the rat is moving through my maze, I set the background color of my maze path to red 
every time the rat travels on that specific path. But, for some reason that is not happening. I'm not sure why at all. Please help!

```
package TheMaze;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;   
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TheMaze {

    static JButton[][] jb;

    //static String r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9;
    static String m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8, m9;
    static int row = 0;
    static int column = 3;

    static char[][] mProtocol;
    static JFrame jf = new JFrame("Mazifying Maze");
    Container contain = new Container();

    public TheMaze(int length, int width) {

        jb = new JButton[length][width];
        mProtocol = new char[length][width];
        contain = new Container();

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < length; y++) {
                jb[y][x] = new JButton();
                jf.add(jb[y][x]);
            }
        }

        jb[2][0].setBackground(Color.black);
        jb[4][0].setBackground(Color.black);
        jb[2][97].setBackground(Color.black);
        jb[2][96].setBackground(Color.black);
        jb[2][95].setBackground(Color.black);
        jb[2][94].setBackground(Color.black);
        jb[2][93].setBackground(Color.black);
        jb[2][92].setBackground(Color.black);
        jb[2][91].setBackground(Color.black);
        .
                .
                .
        Just goes on and on.

                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                if (jb[i][j].getBackground() == Color.black) {
                    mProtocol[i][j] = 'w';
                } else {
                    mProtocol[i][j] = 'p';

                }
            }

            jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            jf.setLayout(new GridLayout(length, width));
            jf.setSize(1400, 700);

            jf.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public static void ratMessage(String ratPos) {

        System.out.println(ratPos);
        String ratMessage = ratPos;

        String r1 = ratMessage.substring(0, 1);
        String r2 = ratMessage.substring(1, 2);
        String r3 = ratMessage.substring(2, 3);
        String r4 = ratMessage.substring(3, 4);
        String r5 = ratMessage.substring(4, 5);
        String r6 = ratMessage.substring(5, 6);
        String r7 = ratMessage.substring(6, 7);
        String r8 = ratMessage.substring(7, 8);
        String r9 = ratMessage.substring(8, 9);

        if (r2.equals('r')) {
            jb[row - 1][column].setBackground(Color.red);
            row = row - 1;

        }
        if (r4.equals('r')) {
            jb[row][column - 1].setBackground(Color.red);
            column = column - 1;
        }
        if (r6.equals('r')) {
            jb[row][column + 1].setBackground(Color.red);
            column = column + 1;
        }
        if (r8.equals('r')) {
            jb[row + 1][column].setBackground(Color.red);
            row = row + 1;
        }

    }

    public static String mazeMessage() {

        if (row - 1 < 0 && column - 1 < 0) {

            m1 = "o";

            m2 = "o";

            m3 = "o";

            m4 = "o";

            m5 = "r";

            m6 = mProtocol[row][column + 1] + "";

            m7 = "o";

            m8 = mProtocol[row + 1][column] + "";

            m9 = mProtocol[row + 1][column + 1] + "";
        } else if (row + 1 > 99 && column + 1 > 99) {
            m1 = mProtocol[row - 1][column - 1] + "";
            m2 = mProtocol[row - 1][column] + "";
            m3 = "o";
            m4 = mProtocol[row][column - 1] + "";
            m5 = "r";
            m6 = "o";
            m7 = "o";
            m8 = "o";
            m9 = "o";
        } else if (row - 1 < 0 && column + 1 > 99) {
            m1 = "o";
            m2 = "o";
            m3 = "o";
            m4 = mProtocol[row][column - 1] + "";
            m5 = "r";
            m6 = "o";
            m7 = mProtocol[row + 1][column - 1] + "";
            m8 = mProtocol[row + 1][column] + "";
            m9 = "o";
        } else if (row + 1 > 99 & column - 1 < 0) {
            m1 = "o";
            m2 = mProtocol[row - 1][column] + "";
            m3 = mProtocol[row - 1][column + 1] + "";
            m4 = "o";
            m5 = "r";
            m6 = mProtocol[row][column + 1] + "";
            m7 = "o";
            m8 = "o";
            m9 = "o";

        } else if (row - 1 < 0) {
            m1 = "o";
            m2 = "o";
            m3 = "o";
            m4 = "" + mProtocol[row][column - 1];
            m5 = "r";
            m6 = "" + mProtocol[row][column + 1];
            m7 = mProtocol[row + 1][column - 1] + "";
            m8 = mProtocol[row + 1][column] + "";
            m9 = mProtocol[row + 1][column + 1] + "";

        } else if (row + 1 > 99) {
            m1 = mProtocol[row - 1][column - 1] + "";
            m2 = mProtocol[row - 1][column] + "";
            m3 = mProtocol[row - 1][column + 1] + "";
            m4 = mProtocol[row][column - 1] + "";
            m5 = "r";
            m6 = mProtocol[row][column + 1] + "";
            m7 = "o";
            m8 = "o";
            m9 = "o";

        } else if (column - 1 < 0) {
            m1 = "o";
            m2 = mProtocol[row - 1][column] + "";
            m3 = mProtocol[row - 1][column + 1] + "";
            m4 = "o";
            m5 = "r";
            m6 = mProtocol[row][column + 1] + "";
            m7 = "o";
            m8 = mProtocol[row + 1][column] + "";
            m9 = mProtocol[row + 1][column + 1] + "";

        } else if (column + 1 > 99) {

            m1 = mProtocol[row - 1][column - 1] + "";
            m2 = mProtocol[row - 1][column] + "";
            m3 = "o";
            m4 = mProtocol[row][column - 1] + "";
            m5 = "r";
            m6 = "o";
            m7 = mProtocol[row + 1][column - 1] + "";
            m8 = mProtocol[row + 1][column] + "";
            m9 = "o";

        } else {
            m1 = mProtocol[row - 1][column - 1] + "";
            m2 = mProtocol[row - 1][column] + "";
            m3 = mProtocol[row - 1][column + 1] + "";
            m4 = mProtocol[row][column - 1] + "";
            m5 = "r";
            m6 = mProtocol[row][column + 1] + "";
            m7 = mProtocol[row + 1][column - 1] + "";
            m8 = mProtocol[row + 1][column] + "";
            m9 = mProtocol[row + 1][column + 1] + "";
        }

        return m1 + m2 + m3 + m4 + m5 + m6 + m7 + m8 + m9;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {//throws IOException{

        System.setProperty("java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort", "true");

        TheMaze mz = new TheMaze(100, 100);

        try {

            ServerSocket svs = new ServerSocket(13000);
            System.out.println("Has not Connected");
            Socket socks = svs.accept();
            System.out.println("Has Connected");
            DataOutputStream p = new DataOutputStream(socks.getOutputStream());
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(socks.getInputStream());

            DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(socks.getInputStream());

            String theMazeMessage = "ooowrwwpw";

            System.out.println("first message" + theMazeMessage);
            p.writeUTF(theMazeMessage);

            while (row != 99 && column != 87) {

                System.out.println("in loop");// still going, not yet reached end of maze.
                String recieving = d.readUTF();
                System.out.println(recieving);
                ratMessage(recieving);

                p.writeUTF(theMazeMessage);
                System.out.println(theMazeMessage);
            }

            socks.close();
            p.close();
            isr.close();
            d.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            String theMazeMessage = m1 + m2 + m3 + m4 + m5 + m6 + m7 + m8 + m9;

        }
    }
}
```

AND the Rat class:

```
package therat;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class TheRat {

    static String m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8, m9;
    static String theMazeMessage;
    static String identifier;

    public static void theMazeMessage(String mazePos) {

        String theMazeMessage = mazePos;

        m1 = theMazeMessage.substring(0, 1);
        m2 = theMazeMessage.substring(1, 2);
        m3 = theMazeMessage.substring(2, 3);
        m4 = theMazeMessage.substring(3, 4);
        m5 = theMazeMessage.substring(4, 5);
        m6 = theMazeMessage.substring(5, 6);
        m7 = theMazeMessage.substring(6, 7);
        m8 = theMazeMessage.substring(7, 8);
        m9 = theMazeMessage.substring(8, 9);

        System.out.println(mazePos);

    }

    public static String Move() {

        if (m8.equals("p")) {
            identifier = goDown();

        } else if (m2.equals("p")) {
            identifier = goUp();

        } else if (m4.equals("p")) {
            identifier = goLeft();

        } else if (m6.equals("p")) {
            identifier = goRight();

        }
        return identifier;
    }

    public static String goDown() {

        return m1 + m2 + m3 + m4 + 'p' + m6 + m7 + 'r' + m9;

    }

    public static String goUp() {

        return m1 + 'r' + m3 + m4 + 'p' + m6 + m7 + m8 + m9;

    }

    public static String goLeft() {

        return m1 + m2 + m3 + 'r' + 'p' + m6 + m7 + m8 + m9;

    }

    public static String goRight() {

        return m1 + m2 + m3 + m4 + 'p' + 'r' + m7 + m8 + 9;

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {

            Socket sox = new Socket("localhost", 13000);
            System.out.println("Connected");
            DataOutputStream ps = new DataOutputStream(sox.getOutputStream());

            DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(sox.getInputStream());
            boolean done = false;
            while (!done) {
                System.out.println("in loop");
                String mazeMessage = d.readUTF();
                System.out.println("mazeMessage is " + mazeMessage);
                theMazeMessage(mazeMessage);
                String s = Move();
                System.out.println(s);
                ps.writeUTF(s);
                ps.flush();

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You violating the single thread rules of Swing in the `ratMessage` method to start with

Answer (score 3):

The primary issue that I can see is in the `ratMessage` method where you are comparing a `String` value with a `char`

```
if (r2.equals('r'))
```

This isn't going to work, because a `String` and a `char` can never be equal, they're the wrong type.  If instead, you change them to be more like...

```
if (r2.equals("r"))
```

You should have more success.

There are number of other gotcha's which are going to cause some grief.  `static` is not a solution.  Over use of `static` is going to come back and bite you, hard.  Where possible, you should be relying on passing valid references of the objects you need to interact with.

Personally, I'd devise a series of `interface`s which would describe the expected contract, such as `ratMessage`, for example.  Your UI would implement this interface and a reference of it should be passed to the main "comms" class, which reading information from the rat.

You are, also, violating the single thread rules of Swing.  Swing requires that all interactions and updates to any UI component must be done from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  Because you're running your main loop from the "main" thread and calling `ratMessage` which is then updating the buttons, you're violating this rule.

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details.

The solution might involve a `SwingWorker` for simplicity or `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` for quickness of change...